# SQL Access 2016 doesn't seem to recognize my code

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, create-table

I have a problem with my SQL access 2016, i have followed the instructions carefully yet it seems to not work, it doesn't point out anything to correct.

-- MY SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS (
 
   NUMDE NUMBER (3)    PRIMARY KEY,
   NUMCE NUMBER (4)  REFERENCES CENTROS(NUMCE),
   DIREC NUMBER (3),
   TIDIR TEXT (1),
   PRESU NUMBER (3, 1),
   DEPDE NUMBER(3) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTOS (NUMDE),
   NOMDE VARCHAR2(20)
  );
```

Comment: Well, they are reference for the table, it's in Spanish but Nomde and numde stand for "Nombre Departamento" and "Numero Departamento".

Comment: Are you migrating from Oracle to MS Access ?

Comment: I'm not sure at all what Oracle it is.. But this is Access 2016, I was trying to learn in depth with creating tables via SQL. Pardon me if I'm not so clear, I've been barely with Select a and a few more things

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS (
 
   NUMDE DECIMAL (3)    PRIMARY KEY,
   NUMCE DECIMAL (4)    REFERENCES CENTROS(NUMCE),
   DIREC DECIMAL (3),
   TIDIR nchar(1),
   PRESU DECIMAL (3, 1),
   DEPDE DECIMAL(3)     REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTOS (NUMDE),
   NOMDE VARCHAR(20)
  );
```

Comment: Syntax error in field definition (it's on spanish I hope I didnt spell anything wrong) 

Comment: There is no syntax error. It is tested (leaving out CENTROS) and verified: 
_Commands completed successfully. 
Completion time: 2023-03-21T09:57:25.2382744+01:00_.

Comment: Hmm. Then I don't know exactly what's happening to my SQL, well when it gives me the error it doesn't point out the wrong line at all. Is there any tip I may ask for?

Comment: Always use SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) to test and debug queries. It provides full debugging and error information.